# Haskell - Caching third party API token across requests

Tags: haskell, state

The following code is designed to cache a `(UTCTime, Text)` value that keeps the `Text` token around until it expires, preventing needing to re-fetch the token each time this third party API is called. I feel like this duplication in `APIDefaults` and `APIEnv` could be removed, perhaps through a type parameter, though there may be a better way of doing this than storing the `MVar` inside `APIDefaults`.

`APIError` and `getApiToken` are just stubbed out as their detail is not relevant here, but in my code these are not implemented as they are below, so you can just ignore those.

```
data APIDefaults = APIDefaults
  { apidefManager :: Manager
  , apidefPool :: ConnectionPool
  , apidefTokenRef :: MVar (UTCTime, Text)
  }

data APIEnv = APIEnv
  { apienvManager :: Manager
  , apienvPool :: ConnectionPool
  , apienvToken :: Text
  }

data APIToken = APIToken
  { apiTokenAccessToken :: Text
  , apiTokenExpiresIn :: Int
  }

data APIError

fireApiRequest
  :: MonadLogger m
  => MonadUnliftIO m
  => ReaderT APIEnv m (Either APIError a)
  -> ReaderT APIDefaults m (Either APIError a)
fireApiRequest req = runExceptT $ do
  env <- do
    t <- lift readCachedToken
    case t of
      Nothing -> fetchToken
      Just (savedExpiry, token) -> lift $ do
        updateTokenRef (savedExpiry, token)
        apd <- ask
        return (createAPIEnv apd token)
  ExceptT $ lift (runReaderT req env)

readCachedToken
  :: MonadUnliftIO m
  => ReaderT APIDefaults m (Maybe (UTCTime, Text))
readCachedToken = runMaybeT $ do
  mv <- lift (asks apidefTokenRef)
  (savedExpiry, token) <- MaybeT $ liftIO (tryTakeMVar mv)
  now <- getCurrentTime
  guard (savedExpiry > now)
  return (savedExpiry, token)

updateTokenRef
  :: MonadUnliftIO m
  => (UTCTime, Text)
  -> ReaderT APIDefaults m ()
updateTokenRef value = do
  tokenRef <- asks apidefTokenRef
  void $ liftIO (tryPutMVar tokenRef value)

fetchToken
  :: MonadLogger m
  => MonadUnliftIO m
  => ExceptT APIError (ReaderT APIDefaults m) APIEnv
fetchToken = do
  now <- getCurrentTime
  adef <- lift ask
  token <- getApiToken
  let expiration = addUTCTime (fromIntegral $ apiTokenExpiresIn token) now
  lift $ updateTokenRef (expiration, apiTokenAccessToken token)
  return $ createAPIEnv adef (apiTokenAccessToken token)

getApiToken :: Monad m => m APIToken
getApiToken =
  return undefined

createAPIEnv :: APIDefaults -> Text -> APIEnv
createAPIEnv adef token =
  APIEnv (apidefManager adef) (apidefPool adef) token
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the type of `apidefTokenRef` unnecessarily exposes internal details. Perhaps it would better to parameterize `APIDefaults` with a monad and hide the code that gets the token behind a monadic action, like this:

```
data APIDefaults m = APIDefaults
  { apidefManager :: Manager
  , apidefPool :: ConnectionPool
  , apidefTokenAction :: m APIToken 
  }
```

I'm also making it return the `APIToken` type instead of `Text`. It's good to have a more precise type for it than `Text`, let's not fall prey to [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession)!

Now `APIEnv` seems a bit redundant. Instead of reading the token from `APIEnv`, functions in need of it can simply execute the token action each time. Or perhaps we could define a function like

```
sequenceToken :: Monad m => APIDefaults m -> m (APIDefaults Identity)
sequenceToken r = do
    token <- apidefTokenAction r
    pure (r { apidefTokenAction = Identity token })
```

---

But how to define the token action itself? Here I will indulge in a bit of over-abstraction and define this typeclass:

```
class Perishable p where
    lifetime :: p -> NominalDiffTime
```

for values which have a certain [lifetime](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:NominalDiffTime) during which they are valid. Of course, `APIToken` will have an instance.

What type should the function which creates the token action have? It will be something like

```
makeRefresher :: Perishable p => IO p -> IO (IO p)
```

(Working in `IO` for simplicity, the real function would likely work in `MonadUnliftIO`.)

The argument is an action that obtains the perishable value. But why the outer `IO` in the result? because `makeRefresher` will have to set up some reference—like an `MVar`—that will be used across successive invocations of the resulting action:

```
makeRefresher obtain = do
    ref <- newMVar _initialValueHole
    return $ _actualTokenActionHole
```

What should be on the `MVar`? Perhaps a `Maybe (UTCTime, p)`. It would be `Nothing` initially to signify that no perishable value has been obtained yet, and later it would become `Just (someTime,somePerishable)`. We have the time of creation and the expected lifetime of the `Perishable`, so we can decide whether to return the current value or invoke `obtain` again.

Instead of `Maybe`, I would perhaps use my own type, for clarity:

```
data PerishableState p = NoPerishableYet
                       | PerishableObtainedAt UTCTime p
```

Also, I would try to manipulate the `MVar` with functions like [`modifyMVar_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) to avoid deadlocks if there's an exception while obtaining the token.

---

One potential disadvantage of this solution is that the token "state" becomes harder to inspect because it's hidden behind an opaque action. Perhaps some logging effect should be added.